# Reuse Hadoop code in Spark efficiently?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-spark, hadoop2

hi,I have code written in Hadoop and now I try to migrate to Spark. The mappers and reducers are fairly complex. So I tried to reuse Mapper and Reducer classes of already existing **Hadoop** code inside **spark** program. Can somebody tell me how do I achieve this?

**EDIT:**

So far, I have been able to reuse **mapper** class of standard hadoop word-count example in spark, implemented as below
**wordcount.java**

```
import scala.Tuple2; 

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.*;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public final class wordcount  extends Configured  implements Serializable {
  public static int main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("spark://IMPETUS-I0203:7077").setAppName("wordcount");
        JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf); //created Spark context
        JavaRDD<String> rec = ctx.textFile("hdfs://localhost:54310/input/words.txt"); //Record Reader

  //creating a  Pair RDD whose key=some arbitrary number, value = a Record
        JavaPairRDD<LongWritable,Text> lines =rec.mapToPair(s->new Tuple2<LongWritable,Text>(new LongWritable(s.length()),new Text(s)));

  //transforming 'lines' RDD to another such that it returns for example ('word',1) tuple.
      JavaPairRDD<Text,IntWritable> ones = lines.flatMapToPair(it -> {

          NotSerializableException notSerializable = new NotSerializableException();
          JobConf conf = new JobConf(new Configuration(), wordcount.class);
          conf.setJobName("WordCount");
          conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
          conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
          Path inp = new Path("hdfs://localhost:54310/input/darcy.txt");
          FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, inp);
          FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, out);

          WordCountMapper mapper = new WordCountMapper();
        mapper.configure(conf);
        OutputCollector<Text,IntWritable> output = new outputcollector<Text,IntWritable>() ;

            mapper.map(it._1, it._2 , output, Reporter.NULL);

          return  ((outputcollector)output).getList();
        });

        ones.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://localhost:54310/output/41");
        return 0;
  }
}
```

**WordCountMapper.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class WordCountMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>,Serializable
{
      private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
      private Text word = new Text();

      public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
      {
            NotSerializableException notSerializable = new NotSerializableException();
            String line = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
            {  
               word = new Text();
               word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
               output.collect(word, one);
            }
       }
}
```

**outputcollector.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;
import scala.Tuple2;

public class outputcollector<K extends Object, V extends Object> implements OutputCollector<K, V>{
    private List<Tuple2<K,V>> writer = new ArrayList<Tuple2<K,V>>();
    @Override
    public void collect(K key, V value) {
        try{
            writer.add(new Tuple2<K,V>(key,value));
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e+ "\n\n****output collector error\n\n");
        }
    }
    public List<Tuple2<K,V>> getList(){
        return writer;
    }
}
```

This code works perfectly fine and I can **successfully** submit this spark job. It is somehow highly **inefficient** compared pure spark program. It takes about 50 times longer than a simple spark word-count example. Input file is **1 GB**. Input file exists on **HDFS**. Running in **standalone** mode.

I am unable to find the reason why this code is as **slow** as a sloth. Here, I am using WordCountMapper.java in order to simply collect the **pair(word,1)**. That is also working in memory. So I don't see why my code has to be so slower than standard spark word-count example.

So, can anyone suggest a **better approach** of reusing WordCountMapper.java (hadoop mapper) in spark? or explain the reason why it is so slow? Or anything that helps achieve my ultimate goal? (mentioned in my question at the top).

Comment: You can't re-use it!

Comment: you are doing a wordcount and you are saying that the mapper and reducer are complex? It's better to build your application from scratch considering the **old** mapreduce workflow!

Comment: I have 20k lines of code in hadoop. My aim is to reuse some part of that code in spark. I've taken this simple wordcount example as I am just researching whether I can reuse any hadoop code in Spark. I want to explore every possible way through which I can reuse Hadoop code.

Comment: Like I said before you can't! You can just use the workflow! It's the same programming paradigm after all

Comment: You might wanna take a look at this. Matei zaharia said you could reuse it. http://mail-archives.us.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201406.mbox/%3C580C94D3-FD05-4298-86E0-AC5C8C953D7C@gmail.com%3E

Comment: Yes Matei is talking about the workflow!

Answer (score 0):

The basic way of converting a mapreduce to spark is:

```
rdd.mapPartitions(partition -> 
    setup() //map setup
    partition.map( item => 
        val output = process(item) 
        if (!partition.hasNext) {
           // Some cleanup code here
        }
    )
).groupByKey().mapPartitions( //similarly for reduce code).saveAsHadoopFile(//params) //To save on HDFS
```

Following link points to a set of two articles on cloudera. Not everything is discussed but if you go through it you get the gist of how to convert some parts of hadoop jobs into spark. For example how to do setup and cleanup.

http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/09/how-to-translate-from-mapreduce-to-apache-spark/

**Note**: I have tried converting mapreduce to spark but it has resulted in a slower application. Maybe it is my own inefficiency in using scala or maybe spark is not suited for batch jobs. So be aware of this as well.

Comment: Thanks Sohaib. It works. And I think you already know that Inefficiency was coming from the use of groupByKey(). So do you think there any other way around ?

Comment: According to what I believe, groupByKey() is slow because we can not apply reducer locally on each mapper (unlike reduceByKey() where reducer reduces data locally and then shuffles ). So I was asking whether there's a way we could apply groupByKey() locally on each mapper then spark shuffles data and then we could use groupByKey() again on entire cluster?

Comment: You could instead use `reduceByKey` or `aggregateByKey` or `combineByKey`. A little tweaking around these with some encode/decode could help you implement `groupByKey` yourself.

Comment: That may work in most cases, but If our reducer was using 'key' inside it's body, then we can't use ReduceByKey() or aggregateByKey() or combineByKey() because these functions do not give us access to 'key', right. So what do we do then?

Comment: @DazzleR In the worlkflow that I have written your reducer is in the second call to mapPartitiions which has access to both keys and values (since I am accumulating values using groupByKey). You can accumulate values using reduceByKey or aggregateByKey as well and this is what I mean by the previous comment.